# Firebase warning on showing Interstitial Ad from fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, admob

I am implementing Interstitial Ads in my app. I am loading the Ads inside a fragment and showing it on button click and starting an activity on 'onAdClosed()' listner from the fragment.

Here is my code:-

```
public View onCreateView(....){
        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(getActivity());
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(mContext.getString(R.string.admob_ad_unit_id_full_screen));
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().
                addTestDevice("XX_DEVICE_ID").
                build());

mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                super.onAdClosed();

            if(condition)
                startactivity(---, ---);

            // loading ad
            mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().
                        addTestDevice("XX_DEVICE_ID").
                        build());
        }
    }
}

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.mybutton:
                if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                    mInterstitialAd.show();
                } else {
                    startactivity(---, ---);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

**Everything is working perfectly except that every time i click on the button and the ad shows i am getting these warnings:-**

```
 W/Ads: Invoke Firebase method getCurrentScreenClass error.
                                               java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: getCurrentScreenClass []
                                                   at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:624)
                                                   at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:586)
                                                   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.scionintegration.b.f(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:124)
                                                   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.scionintegration.b.e(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:31)
                                                   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.ak.L(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:108)
                                                   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.ak.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:63)
                                                   at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzep$zza$zza.showInterstitial(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfa.show(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd.show(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.subinfra.Fragment.EditProfile.onClick(EditProfile.java:245)
                                                   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5207)
                                                   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21177)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5438)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
```

---

```
   W/Ads: Invoke Firebase method getCurrentScreenName error.
                                               java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[])' on a null object reference
                                                   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.scionintegration.b.e(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:32)
                                                   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.ak.L(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:108)
                                                   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.ak.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:63)
                                                   at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzep$zza$zza.showInterstitial(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfa.show(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd.show(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.subinfra.Fragment.EditProfile.onClick(EditProfile.java:245)
                                                   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5207)
                                                   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21177)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5438)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
```

I searched for help on stackoverflow and google but found none of the question referring to my problem. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: same problem. It doesn´t crash, it shows ads but I get this exception....do you still have this problem?

Comment: Yeah the warning still shows. Have you tried something to solve it?

Comment: nope....but I try. Maybe it´s a bug and we can´t do anything against this. If I find the solution, I will post it here....

Comment: which ver of firebase ads do you use?

Comment: @NickUnuchek Hi, sorry for replying late, i am using com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.0.1

Comment: I have also get same warning like that. No one solution I got. Anyone have solution for this one means, post here. It help to some others. Thanks in advance.